# Understanding Hurwitz' theorem: What does "$z_0$ is a limit point of the zeros of a sequence $\{f_n\}$" mean?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

In Marsden's Basic Complex Analysis, the Hurwitz' Theorem is stated as follows:
[image]

My question is regarding the statement in the last parenthesis: "that is, a zero of $f$ is a limit point of the zeros of the functions $f_n$". Is it also true that a limit point of the zeros of the functions $f_n$ is a zero of $f$?

By the theorem, I know that if there is sequence $z_n \to z_0$ and there is an integer $N$ such that $f_n(z_n)=0$ whenever $n \geq N$, then $f(z_0)=0$, but is that condition equivalent to say that $z_0$ is a limit point of the zeros of the functions $f_n$? If that's the case, I don't know how to make it coincide with the usual definition of [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of a set. If $B$ is the set of the zeros of the functions $f_n$, that is, $B=\{z : f_m(z)=0$ for some $m\}$, then, using the usual definition, $z_0$ is a limit point of $B$ iff every neighbourhood of $z_0$ contains a point of $B$ other than $z_0$ itself, which would imply that there is a sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $B$ converging to $z_0$, and the fact that $\{z_n\} \subset B$ implies that for each $n$, the is some $m$ such that $f_m(z_n)=0$, but how to assure that $m=n$, so that $f_n(z_n)=0$?

Comment: the answer to your question is not only yes, but because of the situation you are in (analytic functions etc) any limit point of the zeroes of $f_n$ cannot skip infinitely many indices, so in fact for any neighborhood $B$ of $w$ the limit point in question, there is an $n(B)$ such that each $f_n, n \ge n(B)$ has a zero in $B$ - this indeed is stronger than the generic definition of a limit point and it is part of Hurwitz theorem statement/proof and holds in this special case of analytic functions - essentially because of the discreteness of the zeroes and the argument principle

Comment: If $z_0$ is a limit point of zeroes of $f_n,$ it would mean that there is a sequence of points $z_{n_k}$ such that $f_{n_k}(z_{n_k})=0$ and $z_{n_k}\to z_0.$ It follows from the theorem that $z_0$ is a zero of $f.$

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho That's what I'm having trouble with. I know that there is a sequence in $B$ such that $z_n \to z_0$, so, for $n=1$, there is $f_{k_1}$ such that $f_{k_1}(z_1)=0$, for $n=2$, there is $f_{k_2}$ such that $f_{k_2}(z_2)=0$, etc. But how do I know that $k_2>k_1$? And I would have $f_{k_n}(z_n)=0$, not  $f_{k_n}(z_{k_n})=0$ nor $f_n(z_n)=0.$

Comment: You fix a Ball of radius $1/n$ centered at $z_0.$ This contains a point from $B$, call it $z_n.$ You have a function $f_{x_n}$ which has a zero at $z_n.$ Now look at all the functions in your sequence $f_n$ where $n\le x_n.$ Remove the zeroes of all those functions from B. You have removed only finitely many points from B. Therefore $z_0$ is a limit point of the new set as well. Now you shrink the radius of Ball at $z_0.$ And repeat the process.

Comment: You will obtain a sequence of function $f_{k_n}$ with zeroes at $z_n$ such that $z_n$ converges to $z_0.$ Now you define a new sequence of function $g_n:=f_{k_n}.$ Observe that $g_n$ converges uniformly on compact sets to $f$ and $g_n(z_n)=0$ for all $n.$ Now you apply Hurwitz theorem to this sequence obtain that $z_0$ is a zero of $f.$

Comment: Don't we need balls of radius $\delta/n$, where $\delta$ is the radius of some open disk contained in the region $A$? When you say "you have removed only finitely many points from $B$", do you mean that the set of zeros of each $f_n$ is finite? I'm not sure I know why, does that hold for all $n$ or for $n$ large? With that argument, one proofs that $g_n(z_n)=0$ for all $n$ and for a different sequence $\{g_n\}$, so it's not true that $f_n(z_n)=0$ for some $n \geq N$?